# PDO Connection established but record not inserted in Cakephp

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert

I am trying to insert the values into the table through controller in CakePhp. I've tested first. It says:

> db connected successfully.

But when I insert something into the table using PDO by prepared statement, it shows an error like

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound.

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `job` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The function I mentioned in my controller is,

```
public function insdb() {

    $sqlInsert = $this->User->query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `job`) VALUES (:name1,:job1)");
    $preparedStatement = $conn->prepare($sqlInsert);
    $preparedStatement->User->execute(array(':name1' => 'Tony', ':job1' => 'gardner'));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like CakePHP at all... CakePHP uses an ORM you're using PDO directly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix CakePHP and pure PDO syntax. The pure PDO way would look like this:

```
$preparedStatement = $conn->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `job`) VALUES (:name1, :job1)");
$preparedStatement->execute(array(':name1' => 'Tony', ':job1' => 'gardener'));
```

The CakePHP way would look like this, assuming your User model is set up correctly and maps to the right table:

```
$this->User->create();
$this->User->save(array('name' => 'Tony', 'job' => 'gardener'));
```

NB: I assume `id` is the primary key of your table, even though that is not included in the `CREATE TABLE` statement you provided.